# AngularJS Accessing C# MVC Index return Object

Tags: c#, angularjs, indexing, view, model

Morning all,

When I do use angularjs to do a http.get I can store the result
    var response = $http.get("somethingUseful")

However, when angularjs handles the routing of the url (specifically the index page)
I've got:

```
Controller.cs:
public ActionResult Index (){
    return View(new FunkyModel())
}
```

within
    Index.cshtml:
    @model FunkyModel

can access Model etc..., happy days!

though in 
    Template.html

what's the easiest way to then access this without doing a JSON.Encode or without having to make a second request?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest - it is not the proper way of using Angular + MVC. You shouldn't expect to share models between back-end and front-end code.

You should use `JsonResult` and send all the data to the view and let Angular load a view for you. In case it is not possible, another request for necessary data is a viable option(not ideal though).

In my opinion building MVC application with Angular on a front-end is a misunderstanding of concepts behind this technologies. Angular is the best when is used as a engine for SPA(Single Page Application), where you can use its routing features, views loading and many many more.